# Running Eclipse in Ubuntu with JRE & JDK installed on Windows beforehand

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I recently installed Ubuntu on my computer. (I'm new to Ubuntu as well).
I have eclipse, JRE & JDK installed and working on my Windows previously. I also have Wine installed on Ubuntu.

My question is that is there any way I can run eclipse on ubuntu without reinstalling the JRE and JDK?

I tried changing the -vm directory to the correct JRE folder (...\Java\JRE7\bin\java.exe). Eclipse launched, but then it says Java returns exit code = 1, and exit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you *ever* try to run the JVM on Wine? It'll be slow, unreliable, and blow up every time JNI is used. I suggest you install the necessary packages (`openjdk-7-jdk` should be fine) and use those.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to ubuntu and just wonder if I could run JVM without installing it again (since I already got it on windows)

Comment: @user2780049 If you have a CD in your car, would it be there in your wife's car too? Having two OSes on one machine is very similar.

Comment: Whenever possible, if you can use a native-unix binary--DO IT.  You'll save yourself SO much hell.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this, but I would suggest you just install the JDK directly in Ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

(from memory).  You will also need a Linux Eclipse.